# Solving efficiently NP problems with infinite precision

Tags: np-complete, computation-models

I heard a few times that if we allow computations with infinite precision, we could have unrealistic powers of computation up to the point of solving NP problems efficiently.

Is it true? If yes:

- what is the model of computations used to define infinitely precise arithmetic? Like do we need to assume that accessing to the n-th digit of a number can be done in constant time and that operations between two numbers is done in constant time? (Otherwise I guess it would be possible to efficiently simulate this in  classical computer using lazy arithmetic.)
- given this model of computation, how would you use it to break NP complete problems?
- is it possible to approximate physically such model, for instance in an analogic way considering the (unrealistic) assumption that there is no noise?

Comment: https://yuvalfilmus.cs.technion.ac.il/Courses/AlgebraicMethods/2017/PolySAT.pdf

Comment: Analog computers work with physical quantities and are much less accurate than what we achieve even with single-precision floating-point. And the discrete nature of matter kills any hope of representing real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One such model of computation is explained in [this note](https://yuvalfilmus.cs.technion.ac.il/Courses/AlgebraicMethods/2017/PolySAT.pdf). In this model of computation, we are allowed to perform arithmetic operations, logical operations, and comparisons on integers of arbitrary precision. We encode Boolean functions $f\colon \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ as bitstrings of length $2^n$, thinking of the index of a bit as encoding a truth assignment. Explicitly, if $i = i_{n-1} 2^{n-1} + \cdots + i_0$, where $i_0,\ldots,i_{n-1} \in \{0,1\}$, then the $i$'th bit of the bitstring (where the $0$th bit is the LSB) is $f(i_0,\ldots,i_{n-1})$.

Given functions $f,g$, we can compute $f \land g, f \lor g, \lnot f$ using bitwise operations. The projection function $(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto x_i$ corresponds to the bitstring
$$
2^{2^{i-1}} \prod_{I \neq i-1} (1 + 2^{2^I})
$$
which can be computed efficiently (in this model) using repeated squaring.

Given a Boolean formula (or even a Boolean circuit) on $n$ inputs, we can efficiently compute the bitstring corresponding to the function computed by the formula. Comparing the result to zero, we can solve SAT.

In fact, we can even solve QBF. Roughly speaking, to implement a quantifier, we decompose the bitstring into two halves, and then either AND them (in the case of $\forall$) or OR them (in the case of $\exists$). This is possible if we also allow the shift operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Basically, all operations could be efficiently implementable in a lazy way, except the comparison to zero that can loop over an exponential number of elements in constant time… so it's cheating a bit but I guess all solutions will cheat similarly ^^